# How can I limit readonly variable scope to a function?

Tags: bash

I'm defining functions in a script with `readonly local` variables like this:

**`test.sh`**

```
function test_function() {
    readonly local foo="bar"
}
```

Before sourcing, `foo` is of course undefined

```
$> echo $foo

$>
```

But then when I source and run the function

```
$> source test.sh
$> test_function
$> echo $foo
bar
$>
```

suddenly the variable has leaked beyond its scope. Removing `readonly` solves the problem. What am I misunderstanding about the use of a`readonly` and `local` and can both be used without this problem?

The use case is that I get errors/warnings, when calling `test_function` multiple times, because the variable is supposed to be readonly, but already defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace:

```
readonly local foo="bar"
```

with:

```
local -r foo="bar"
```

The issue is that `readonly local foo="bar"` defines **two** readonly variables: one named `local` and  one named`foo`.  It does not create any *local* variables.

By contrast, `local -r foo="bar"` creates a variable named `foo` which is *both* local *and* readonly.

As [David C Rankin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3422102/david-c-rankin) points out, once you have created a global read-only variable, you cannot unset it.  You need to close your existing shell and start a new one.

Comment: You have to kill the shell to remove a `readonly` variable. In bash 5, it's really `readonly`. No more `gdb.. attach $$` or any custom trickery allowed. I knew there was a reason I didn't use them...